# Closing Tippy Tooltip triggers link underneath

Tags: html, tippyjs

If a Tippy tooltip happens to be displayed over a link then clicking on the tooltip also unwantedly triggers the underlying link.

```js
tippy('#myButton', {
  content: 'Click this tooltip to close it',
  trigger: 'click'
});
```

```html
<main>
  Clicking on the tooltip to close it navigates to the link.
  <br><br><a href=foo.html>This is the link that will be triggered</a>
  <br><br><button id="myButton">Click me to see tooltip</button>
</main>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>
```

(also available as a Pen if you prefer that https://codepen.io/mpoo/pen/LYLGVBP?editors=1000)

I was hoping there would be a Tippy Prop that would avoid this behaviour but there does not seem to be.

How can the anchor triggering be prevented?

Answer (score 2):

We can temporary disable the links by setting [`pointer-event: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

We can use the `onShow` and `onHide` props to do so:

1. `onShow`: disable all `<a>`'s
2. `onHide`: enable all `<a>`'s

<sup>--> [All props docs](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v5/all-props/)</sup>

```html
<main>
  Clicking on the tooltip to close it navigates to the link.
  
  <br><br><a href=foo.html>This is the link that will be triggered</a>
  <br><br><button id="myButton">Click me to see tooltip</button>
</main>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>

<script>
    tippy('#myButton', {
        content: 'Click this tooltip to close it',
        trigger: 'click',
        onShow: () => toggleLinks('none'),
        onHide: () => toggleLinks('auto')
    });
  
    const toggleLinks = (value) => {
        let links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); // All <a> on page
     // let links = document.querySelectorAll('main a'); // See comment: All <a> as child of <main>
        for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].style.pointerEvents = value;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution @0stone0. I like it a lot but it seems quite a drastic action to disable every link (and other things such as hover styling) on the page. Did you have any other ideas how to stop the tooltip triggering the underlying link?

Comment: Understand that it feels kinda weird to disable them all. Unfortunately it's very hard to know 'what links is beneath the tooltip'. If you don't have 100+ links on the page, I'd just toggle them all. If you know a classname/id of the container where the links are located, you could search only links as child of that element to reduce the number of links.

Comment: EG: in your example, we can replace `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` with something like `document.querySelectorAll('main a')` to only get the links inside `<main>`

Comment: Added a commented line in the JS code section to show what I'm trying to say ;)

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to need to do some selector jiggery pokery to try to only disable the links that we suppose will be underneath the tooltip. I was really hoping that Tippy would have had a simple way to prevent clicks from going through from the tooltip to hit the other elements on the page.

Comment: Don't think Tippy has a way around this. If you don't have to many cases; you could use something like `<a href='' data-tt='link-a'>` to link tooltips to the `<a>`'s and disable only those who are needed. If my answer helped, please consider [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) or [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the answer. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.|

Comment: One other question about this if you have a moment @0stone0 . What is the key to getting this to work correctly with touch events (i.e. mobile phone)?